# How to change React Native Android project name

Tags: android, gradle, apk, react-native

I need to change the name of my React Native Android project.
I changed my `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.[new name here]">`

but when I try to build a release apk I get the following error

```
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
/Users/harrymoreno/programming/contactsPro/android/app/src/main/java/com/contactspro/MainActivity.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainActivity
1 error
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved this by searching through the entire project for instances of the old project name using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) and replacing the string in some places (don't try the files listing strings). At least 4 files need to be edited in order to change app name.

- `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
- `android/app/src/main/PATH/TO/JAVA/FILES/MainActivity.java`
- `android/app/src/main/PATH/TO/JAVA/FILES/MainApplication.java`
- `/android/app/build.gradle`

for example in `/android/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.[change name]"
     minSdkVersion 16
     targetSdkVersion 22
     versionCode 2

/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.[change name]">

/android/app/src/main/java/com/contactspro/MainActivity.java

package com.[change name];
```

Comment: The package name "com.mycompany.myapp" is also case sensitive

Comment: After applying the change suggested by Harry run   `react-native upgrade` to apply changes and resolve the last issues.

Comment: After applying the changes to com.company.product, and moved java files to new directory (product). When I run `react-native upgrade`, it create new MainActivity & MainApplication in parent folder (company).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here was that when you rename the project through react-native command, it create a new folder with the new project name and it raises an error because you have two main files.

I removed the older folder with the old project files and then, everything works fine.